# Laravel query for multiple relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have a required to calculate the invoices status - Open, Paid, Overdue.

My table structure:

```
invoices:
- id
- custome_id
- total_amount
...

invoice_payments
- id
- invoice_id
- amount_received
...
```

Trying:

```
$records->whereHas('invoice', function($query) use ($val) {
    $query->whereHas('invoicePayments', function($_query){
        $_query->sum('amount_received');
    });
});
```

My concern is to get the status for the invoice
- if `invoice->sum('amount') > invoice->invoicePayment->sum('amount_received')`.

I want to do it with the help of whereHas functions not with database raw queries. Please suggest the way to do it.

Comment: Please post what you have tried, and where you became stuck.

Comment: Updated, please check.

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to use a `whereHas` clause, because you need to compare the value from two different tables. Whereas a `whereHas` just executes a nested sub query. You'll have to use a `join` instead.

Comment: And this - _My concern is to get the status for the invoice_ - doesn't make sense. What does it mean?

Comment: I need to search through all invoices for say like "Paid" status.

Comment: By joins you mean the raw queries?

Comment: No, you can still use the query builder. And I'm still not clear on your expected output. Do you only want to find invoices where the payments are equal to or greater than the total amount?

Comment: Kindly see if you can share a sample for this. 
I need Invoices whose payments are greater or equal to total_amount for invoice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query works with pagination:

```
Invoice::where('total_amount', '<=', function($query) {
    $query->selectRaw('SUM(amount_received)')
        ->from('invoice_payments')
        ->where('invoice_id', DB::raw('invoices.id'));
})->paginate();
```